# How to convert htaccess rules to Nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I need to convert below htaccess rule for my Nginx server. Unfortunately it's not working. Can somebody tell me where I have done wrong?

Original htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^other/(.*) /wp-includes/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ext/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/main.css /index.php?style_wrapper=true&template_wrapper=$1&sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/style\.css /nothing_404_404?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/(.*) /wp-content/themes/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^inc/(.*) /wp-content/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(readme\.html|license\.txt|wp-content/debug\.log|wp-includes/$) /nothing_404_404?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(((wp-content|wp-includes)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\/]*))|(wp-admin/(!network\/?)([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\/]+)))(\.txt|/)$ /nothing_404_404?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 [QSA,L]
```

Converted Nginx rule

```
    location /other { 
    rewrite ^/other/(.*) /wp-includes/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; }

    location /file { 
    rewrite ^/file/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; }

    location /ext { 
    rewrite ^/ext/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; }

    location /skin { 
    rewrite ^/skin/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/main.css /index.php?style_wrapper=true&template_wrapper=$1&sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; 
    rewrite ^/skin/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/style\.css /nothing_404_404?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; 
    rewrite ^/skin/(.*) /wp-content/themes/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; } 

    location /inc { 
    rewrite ^/inc/(.*) /wp-content/$1?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        rewrite ^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break;
        rewrite ^/(readme\.html|license\.txt|wp-content/debug\.log|wp-includes/$) /nothing_404_404?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break;
        rewrite ^/(((wp-content|wp-includes)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\/]*))|(wp-admin/(!network\/?)([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\/]+)))(\.txt|/)$ /nothing_404_404?sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break; 
        }
```

Above rules were converted through http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: You are incorrectly using `break` where you should be using `last`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: thanks, though it did changed the behavior but my problem still there. css files are returned with 404 error. it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" but the files is there @RichardSmith

Comment: You might want to increase your error logging and enable the rewrite log. I use: `error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug; rewrite_log on;`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) for details.

Comment: hello sir, here is my debug report for the last request. its a long file but maybe if you look into first 100 line you'll know whats wrong. what i can understand from the report is it cant find the file into the location its looking into. http://pastebin.com/6HRAqckZ @RichardSmith

Comment: I am looking at line 624, and the pathname: `/var/www/html/website/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/twentysixteen/main.css`. It doesn't match the rules in your original question (so I assume you have been trying alternatives), but you have an extra `twentysixteen` path segment, which will result in a 404 response.

Comment: i am really sorry. here is the correct debug report. http://pastebin.com/UuDsuxTE @RichardSmith

Comment: yes you are correct. there are 2 theme folder. `2016/11/17 14:08:54 [notice] 10823#10823: *3 rewritten data: "/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/twentysixteen/main.css", args: "sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234", client: 103.205.134.110, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /skin/twentysixteen/main.css HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com", referrer: "http://example.com/" ` but how can i solve it? most probably this rule is causing issue `rewrite ^/skin/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/main.css /index.php?style_wrapper=true&template_wrapper=$1&sEyM_hide_my_wp=1234 break;` @RichardSmith